# Unwrapping a Kotlin hashmap in Thymeleaf inside of Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Kotlin function which creates a model with a hashmap as shown below

```
@GetMapping("/")
fun index(model: Model): Mono<String> {
    model.addAttribute("images", imageService.findAllImages()?.flatMap { image ->
        Mono.just(image)
            .zipWith(repository.findByImageId(image?.id!!).collectList())
            .map({ imageAndComments: Tuple2<Image?, MutableList<learningspringboot.images.Comment>> ->
                hashMapOf<String, Any?>(
                    "id" to imageAndComments.t1?.id,
                    "name" to imageAndComments.t1?.name,
                    "comments" to imageAndComments.t2)
            }).log("findAllImages")
    })

    model.addAttribute("extra", "DevTools can also detech code changes.")
    return Mono.just("index")
}
```

**Image.kt**

```
package learningspringboot.images

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id

data class Image(@Id var id: String? = null, var name: String? = null)
```

**Comment.kt**

```
package learningspringboot.images

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id

data class Comment @JvmOverloads constructor(@Id private var id: String? = null, private var imageId: String? = null, private var comment: String? = null) {
}
```

In my Thymeleaf template I have

```
<ul><li th:each = "Comment :${image.comments}" th:text = "${image.comments}"></li></ul>
```

Which gives me this lines like

[Comment(id=5a623d5d2298352bc4929866, imageId=0d46b575-b6ce-48e2-988a-ebe62ebc2ceb, comment=test), Comment(id=5a623d8b2298352bc4929867, imageId=0d46b575-b6ce-48e2-988a-ebe62ebc2ceb, comment=test23)]

Which shows the comment record as is with the MongoDB keys/ids and everything else. This is not what I want.
I also have this in my Thymeleaf template

```
<ul><li th:each = "Comment :${image.comments}" th:text = "${comment == null ? 'empty' : comment.Comment}"></li></ul>
```

Which shows the word **empty** for each comment record.

The comment record in the database looks like

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a623d5d2298352bc4929866"), "imageId" : "0d46b575-b6ce-48e2-988a-ebe62ebc2ceb", "comment" : "test", "_class" : "learningspringboot.comments.Comment" }
```

The image records in the database looks like

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a623d5d2298352bc4929866"), "imageId" : "0d46b575-b6ce-48e2-988a-ebe62ebc2ceb", "comment" : "test", "_class" : "learningspringboot.comments.Comment" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a623d8b2298352bc4929867"), "imageId" : "0d46b575-b6ce-48e2-988a-ebe62ebc2ceb", "comment" : "test23", "_class" : "learningspringboot.comments.Comment" }
```

How can I unwrap the comments records so that I only see the "comment" values and not the "_id" or "imageId" values?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I have a `hashmap<string>,arraylist<image>`.
So I *simply* need to loop through all the image elements in the array list using thymeleaf. I'm pretty sure that this has been done before, I'll just need to find a good example and do some reading.

I was able to use the following code

```
<th:block th:each="Comment : ${image.comments}">
    <ul th:each="comment : ${Comment}">
        <li th:text="${comment.comment}"></li>
    </ul>
</th:block>
```

And now I can move on.